# Project from view using photoshop

Tags: texturing

Im trying to follow this tutorial but using 2.8 and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0qaB-y8qow

I linked my photoshop via both the folder and the exe in the preferences>image editor

I found the external button but I just ge this error

"operator bpy.ops.paint.image from view poll expected"

Any help?

Comment: I'd recommend watching better and more recent tutorials. Check out CGMatter's videos about projection painting.

Comment: He has no videos on using photoshop to project from

Comment: Unless you need specific functionality from Photoshop, you can do it all directly in Blender.

Comment: Yes, I do need something from Photoshop

Answer (score 2):

Just incase anyone else needs this I figured it out, it only works in the stable release in Blender 2.8 and I was using the old version back in July

Link your image editor by going to Preferences > file paths > image editor > click on the EXE of your program

Then to project from the editor go into texture paint > Options > External > Quick edit

Save to apply save the file, make sure you only have one layer it will mess up. Then hit "apply" under external.